# How would a Quickbeam Staff +3 affect a Dragonborn's Close Blast 3 breath attack?

Tags: dnd-4e, magic-items, dragonborn

I am currently playing fourth edition Dungeons and Dragons and am a level 19 sorcerer. I have a quickbeam staff but am not sure how it should work.

I am dragonborn and using my Dragon Breath as a minor. The attack is close blast 3 and affects all creatures in the area of effect. The utility quick beam staff reads "Increase the range of your arcane powers by a number of squares equal to this staff's enchantment bonus." The enchantment bonus is currently plus 3.

How would this affect the attack? Would it increase the Blast or the range of its casting?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, Quickbeam Staff is a type of superior implement that (if you take a feat for proficiency with them) increases thunder damage and forced movement distance. Superior implements can also have enchantments, which would have to be the actual source of the utility power you name. Providing the name of the enchantment you're using would make it easier to give a good answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### By default: No effect

As stated by Oblivious Sage, Dragon Breath is not normally an Arcane power. The power you described only affects Arcane powers, and thus would have no effect on Dragon Breath.

However, the feat Ancient Soul can turn Dragon Breath into an Arcane power, so let's assume you take that.

### With Ancient Soul: Still no effect

The item's power is described as increasing the range of an attack power used with it. However, a Close power doesn't have a range. It has a *size*, indicated by the number at the end, which is distinct from a range, as Area powers have both size and range. Therefore, the utility power would normally have no effect on Dragon Breath.

However, the feat Hurl Breath can turn Dragon Breath into (if I recall the numbers correctly) an Area Burst 2 Within 10. If we assume you also take that feat, we can finally see some effects.

### With both Ancient Soul and Hurl Breath: Increases how far away you can place the burst when used as an Area power

Hurl Breath gives you the option to use Dragon Breath as an Area Burst 2 Within 10. An Area power has both a size (how big the area of effect is) and a range (how far away you can place the origin square of the effect), with the first number being the size and the second being the range. As the utility power described increases the *range* of the power, that is what would be affected.

Therefore, assuming a +3 enhancement bonus on your implement, as well as the two necessary feats, the utility power would allow you to upgrade Dragon Breath into an Area Burst 2 Within 13, but would still have no effect if Dragon Breath is used as a Close Blast.

Comment: Thanks for the info. My sorcerer has both "Ancient Soul" and "Hurl Breath" and my DM argued about the use of my staff until I showed him this. Thank you and have a nice day!

Comment: Are you sure about this? I wouldn't expect the staff to affect Dragon Breath because it isn't an implement power.

Comment: @Passage That depends on the wording of the power. Many item powers and properties even apply to attacks not done through them. As we were not given the actual name of the enchantment on the staff, I only have what was written in the question to go by, and that wording allows it to work for any Arcane power that has a range.

Answer (score 3):

#### Quickbeam will not affect your Dragon Breath at all.

The Quickbeam enchantment's utility power modifies your *arcane* powers. A dragonborn's Dragon Breath power does **not** have the arcane keyword, so it is not an arcane power, and therefore is not modified by Quickbeam's utility power.

Comment: While this is correct in a vacuum, the feat Ancient Soul turns Dragon Breath into an Arcane power.